# Is there the way to build the menu structure and output to JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, menu

I want to build the menu structure such as the WP menu structure.

[image]

So, Is there the way to build the menu structure and output to JSON data? Or please suggest to me the JS library if exist.

Thanks,

Comment: Why -1. It is a valid question. I am furious by people who always try to criticize others. That is an open community to share knowledge, not where criticism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check
https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

this is a Demo
https://dbushell.com/Nestable/

it is exactly what you want, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out http://www.treejs.cn/v3/demo.php#_301

it has all the things you need ie drag and drop ajax load large data management